# Why is Surface film a stretched membrane due to surface tension

Tags: surface-tension

> Surface tension is the property of liquid at rest by virtue of which the liquid surface tends to occupy minimum surface area and behave like a stretched membrane.

If surface tension is property of liquid at rest by virtue of which liquid tends to occupy minimum surface area, then why it behaves like a stretched membrane as stretched surface have more surface area?

Comment: A stretched membrane has more surface area than what?

Comment: @Brionius A stretched membrane has more surface area than a surface which is not stretched.By the following example what I am trying to tell will be clear to you. An inflated balloon has more surface area than one which is not inflated.

Answer (score 1):

I think the key is in the word 'behave'. The surface is not stretched (as this would indeed lead to larger surface area), but rather it behaves as such i.e. if you push into it, it will recoil to its original position as if it where a stretched membrane